# CrystalReportViewer print

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I would like to access the Print event of CrystalReportViewer(while I click the Print button of CrystalReportViewer) in ASP.NET C#, How ?

Comment: Nicole - Is this using WinForms or ASP.NET. What language are you using C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 7):

Something like the below should work. Hope it helps.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (ToolStrip ts in crystalReportViewer1.Controls.OfType<ToolStrip>())
        {
            foreach (ToolStripButton tsb in ts.Items.OfType<ToolStripButton>())
            {
                //hacky but should work. you can probably figure out a better method
                if (tsb.ToolTipText.ToLower().Contains("print"))
                {
                    //Adding a handler for our propose
                    tsb.Click += new EventHandler(printButton_Click);
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Printed");
    }
```

Comment: This version of the hack will only work with an english version of the viewer, as the toolstrip will change with the language used in the UI. A french version of the hack would be  'tsb.ToolTipText.ToLower().Contains("imprimer")' for example.

Comment: Is there any chance that you can convert this one to `vb.net?`

Comment: Alternatively use `(tsb.AccessibleName == "Print Report")`, independently of  ui language.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a new answer but here is the above in C++ using .NET framework objects etc.:

```
    CRXViewerNetControl(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // OK, go though the CRViewer and find the Print Button in the toolbar.  When we find it,
        // attach a "Click" event handler so that we can detect the operator clicking the button to
        // print the report.
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < CRXViewer->Controls->Count; i++)
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip^>(CRXViewer->Controls[i]))
            {
                System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip^ ctlToolStrip = dynamic_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip^>(CRXViewer->Controls[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < ctlToolStrip->Items->Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dynamic_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton^>(ctlToolStrip->Items[j]))
                    {
                        System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton^ ctlToolStripButton = dynamic_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton^>(ctlToolStrip->Items[j]);
                        if (ctlToolStripButton->ToolTipText->ToLower()->Contains("print"))
                        {
                            //Adding a handler for our propose
                            ctlToolStripButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &CRXViewerNetControl::printButton_Click);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

private: System::Void printButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {   
        MessageBox::Show("Printed");
    }
```