# Crystal Reports ASP.NET Web Viewer - Trigger event when Print

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

How can I trigger and event or detect a postback is for printing purposes when the user "prints" the report?

I'd like to update a field in the Database for LastPrintedDate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
.....update your db..
}
```

**EDIT**

also check out this

[***crystal report viewer print***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722796/1268469)

Comment: I agree that's the right starting point however a PostBack can happen for many reasons other than printing.  How do I detect that the PostBack is because the Viewer is rendering the report for print?

Comment: Are you using crystal reports toolbar for printing or your own print buttons ? If you have your own printroutine you already know where to check..

Comment: I would like to use the print functionality build into the viewer (ie. the button on the Crystal Report Toolbar).