# In asp.net, how do I override Crystal Report Viewer's print button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, crystal-reports-2010

I've created my own print button(no print dialog, select printer, papersource) but would like to hide it and override Crystal Report Viewer's built-in print button. Looking at this site: http://forums.asp.net/t/1295479.aspx?how+to+catch+print+button+click+event+in+Crystal+report, it looks to be possible but when debugging, my ReportViewer1.Controls(1).Controls count is 0 so I am unable to access the button.

I also looked at this too but I don't think this is more a windows control and not web realted: [CrystalReportViewer print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685568/crystal-report-viewer-print). Haven't really tried.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't possible. The first link points to the rdlc control, not crystal. You need to create your own buttons or toolbar if possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993938/how-to-print-from-asp-net-crystalreport-on-client-side-printer/25994086#25994086

Comment: @reckface, I think you are right. I've had to hack around it with an external button. Based on the links I provided, I was hopeful that it could be done.